# JSHint: Function conventions

Tags: javascript, node.js, naming-conventions, jslint, jshint

I would like my JSHint to yell at me when I don't follow Crockford's function conventions - i.e.:

"There should be no space between the name of a function and the `(` (left parenthesis) of its parameter list. There should be one space between the `)` (right parenthesis) and the `{` (left curly brace) that begins the statement body"

Is there an option to enable this? I thought `"white":true` would work but it doesn't seem to.  I know JSLint will complain about this as well.

My `.jshintrc`:

`{
  "white": true,
  "node": true,
  "browser": true,
  "esnext": true,
  "bitwise": true,
  "camelcase": true,
  "curly": true,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "immed": true,
  "indent": 2,
  "latedef": true,
  "newcap": true,
  "noarg": true,
  "quotmark": "single",
  "regexp": true,
  "undef": true,
  "nomen": false,
  "unused": true,
  "strict": true,
  "trailing": true,
  "smarttabs": true,
  "sub": true,
  "globals": {
    "angular": false,
    "d3": false
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think that this may be something best done with [jscs](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs). In fact there are  [presets for Crockford](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/blob/master/presets/crockford.json) available.

As JSHint moves to version 3, it will no longer be focused on being a style tool. (Read [JSHint 3 Plans](http://jshint.com/blog/jshint-3-plans/)).